# How to Use the 'From' Address in Email Template like 'no-reply@my-domain name'

Tags: email-template

i created one custom template. once send the Template to my mail id using **Send Test and Verfiy Merge Fields** button. i get the from address like **from:**Me  mail Id****.but how can i impement **no-reply@my mail id** instead of **mail Id**.pls help

Thanks
Kittu

Answer (score 4):

If you setup the email template to be sent via a workflow rule you can specify the email to be sent from an org-wide email address that you can setup as reply@mydomain.com.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response your idea good.but with out Org-wide email address any idea we can implement this logic because 'no-reply@mydomain.com' is fake email so Org-wide email address is not supported with fake email. pls help how to solve this problem..

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried , **"Setup | Email Administration | Deliverability"** , Locate the "Email Security Compliance" section and check the **Enable Sender ID compliance** box then Click Save.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jitendra.i tried what you said i got From Address like this noreply@salesforce.com; on behalf of; TestName [kittu@test.com]. but i want From Address like  TestName[no-reply@test.com] is it possible?

Comment: Ohh, I dont think that its possible kittu. We cannot choose From address. Suggestion from Mark is only close i can think of...

Comment: i understand mark suggestion jitendra but Org-wide email address is not supported with fake email(no-reply@test.com).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it a real email address (or email alias) that you can receive email to, at least temporarily, so that you can validate it as an org-wide address. After you do this, you can redirect or filter the email address to dispose of all mail or remove the alias. Either you need to be able to configure email for your domain, or have the help of someone who does to accomplish this.

Salesforce is very, very careful that you cannot just spoof any email address, and they do this by forcing you to validate the email addresses that you want to send from. I'm sorry, but you are not going to find a way around this using only Salesforce.